# Different ways to pass parameters: String args[] or -D?

Tags: java

I see many Java use `-D` option to pass in some parameters.

And the more familiar way is to pass parameters with `String[] args` to the `main` method.

So what's the difference between these 2 approaches?

### ADD 1

**Is there any scenario when we must prefer one to the other?**

Comment: Stack Overflow generally encourages "one question per question".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The  `-D` switch is for setting system properties rather than for passing arguments to your program. In fact the two approaches don't even send information to the same place: the `String[]` arguments are sent to your program, whereas the switch gets sent to the virtual machine (from which your program can access the properties if it needs to).

Use arguments unless you have a clear idea of why you need a command line switch.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you take a look at my answer. It's down-voted so I'd like to know if anything is wrong. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`Program arguments` are arguments that are passed to your application, which are accessible via the `"args"` String array parameter of your main method. `VM arguments` are arguments such as System properties that are passed to the Java `S W` interpreter.

The `VM arguments` go after the call to your Java interpreter (ie, 'java') and before the Java class. `Program arguments` go after your Java class.

`VM arguments` are passed to the virtual machine and are designed to instruct the V`M to do something`. You can do things like control the heap size, etc.

`Program args` are available via the `args[]` of your `main(String args[])` method

Answer (score 1):

I agree with both the above answers , but the main idea behind it is following
==> Assume you are building a module or a function etc . Now your module has some default settings and these default settings can be overridden by user specified values .. Now here is the catch .. the scope of main(String[] args) is only the main function. These values will be accessible only within the "main" function ... Assume your module is running in a separate thread so how would your module retrieve the user specified value ? So in this case you will pass parameter using -D switch . These values can be accessed using the System.getProperty() method . You can consider them as user specified global value's . Hope this helps

Comment: Interesting scenario.

Answer (score -1):

After using Maven for a while, I want to share some of my thought.

Maven is essentially a plugin execution framework. When I use Maven, I found that it often passes parameters as system properties to plugins through the `-D` option. For example:

```
mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=org.sonatype.mavenbook.weather.Main -Dexec.args="70112"
```

And

```
mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=org.sonatype.mavenbook -DartifactId=simple -Dpackage=org.sonatype.mavenbook -Dversion=1.0-SNAPSHOT
```

In the above commands, the `exec:java` and `archetype:generate` are the Maven `plugin:goal` part.

Suppose we don't use the `-D` approach. Then we have to pass in the parameters as command line arguments, which means our main program (in Maven scenario, it is the `mvn.bat`) **must** incorporate the parsing logic for the parameters of all the various plugins. Each time a new plugin is made and a new parameter is required, the main program have to be modified to reflect that. This is a unwanted coupling between the main program and the plugins. With the `-D` option, plugins can  pick up its parameters **by itself** from the system properties, which is a shortcut to decouple itself from the main program.

Comment: Why this is down voted? If there's something incorrect. Please let me know so I can refine my answer.

Comment: My reply is kind of similar to @Manish's